# Multiple handlers/levels logging in Loguru (Python module)

Tags: logging, loguru

I am making use of [loguru](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) in a Python app.

I have now come to the stage where I would like different handlers to write to `stderr` and file with different levels respectively.

So for `stderr` I want it to only log "DEBUG" level logs (i.e. `logger.debug("my debug log")`).

For write to file I want it to only log "INFO" level logs (i.e. `logger.info("my info log")`).

So in my main `app.py` I have added the loggers as per the [docs](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#no-handler-no-formatter-no-filter-one-function-to-rule-them-all) like so:

```
import sys

from loguru import logger

from my_module import my_function

logger.add(sys.stderr, level="DEBUG")
logger.add("logs/file1.log", level="INFO")

results = my_function()
```

Then I have `my_function()` defined in `my_module.py` like so:

```
from loguru import logger


def my_function():

   logger.info("Start fn")
   # some sql query
   logger.debug("Debug message")
   logger.info("Finishes fn")
```

But this current setup just logs both debug and info levels to both handlers. I read [here](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru/issues/54#issuecomment-461724397) on their github, that importing from loguru in submodules is enough for the future calls to propagated to the configured handlers.

However in my case not, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Try calling logger.remove() first. Also, ensure my_module.py is a submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log a specific level of log messages, exclude the higher levels, you could add a filter:

```py
import logging
import sys
from loguru import logger

logger.remove() # Remove Loguru default handler

logger.add(
  sink=sys.stderr,
  level=logging.DEBUG,
  filter=lambda record: record['level'].name == 'DEBUG'
)
```

In this case, stderr only prints debug logs.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I solved this issue, as the owner on the github repo issues explained it there a while back, same solution.